# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sports Stack Exchange](http://sports.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: No longer relevant as the site is out of beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How does one get 5 points in a football game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3208/how-does-one-get-5-points-in-a-football-game)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is Sachin Tendulkar's 200* not considered as carrying the bat?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/why-is-sachin-tendulkars-200-not-considered-as-carrying-the-bat)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Batting average greater than on-base percentage](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/batting-average-greater-than-on-base-percentage)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is it allowed to wear inner gloves while batting in cricket?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/is-it-allowed-to-wear-inner-gloves-while-batting-in-cricket)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [If time expires does it still count against a down conversion rate?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3356/if-time-expires-does-it-still-count-against-a-down-conversion-rate)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Which rider's time determines result in team time trial?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/which-riders-time-determines-result-in-team-time-trial)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are the names of wakeboard tricks that are performed at the corner of the cable?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3287/what-are-the-names-of-wakeboard-tricks-that-are-performed-at-the-corner-of-the-c)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is there any term used for multiple hat tricks?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3304/is-there-any-term-used-for-multiple-hat-tricks)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [lead baserunner tagged while occupying base he is forced from](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/lead-baserunner-tagged-while-occupying-base-he-is-forced-from)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Fremantle players to have played a grand final](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3284/fremantle-players-to-have-played-a-grand-final)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---